# Sublime Text 3 - Python 3 Build System not importing Python3-specific modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, sublimetext3, build-system

I am on Ubuntu 17.04 LTS, and the default Sublime Text 3 build system fails to import modules that are only for Python 3. For example:

```
>>> import urllib.request
ImportError: No module named request
```

Whereas I can successfully import other modules. What can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is in your home directory a file

```
~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Python/Python.sublime-build
```

which content points to the python executable which should be used for building/running the script.

The content of this file looks like:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

You can adapt it to your needs specifying the Python3 executable instead of Python2 one.

If you also want your Sublime REPL to run Python3 instead of Python2 change in the

```
~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu
```

file the lines:

```
"cmd": ["python", "-i", "-u"]
```

to

```
"cmd": ["python3", "-i", "-u"]
```

(see also [here](https://coderwall.com/p/nhq2gg/setting-up-sublimerepl-with-python3) for some more about it).